# How to allow only data-url attribute to access php file and prevent users from using direct url access?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I only want the below line to access my_file_name.php and prevent user from accessing it by inputting the url. How do I do that?

```
data-url = "../php/my_file_name.php"
```

I am using the Bootstrap Table plugin.

Comment: Send a custom request header with ajax and check if it is present on the server ?

Comment: you can't prevent the user from accessing it via the url, as effectively this is how it is accessed (assuming you're using ajax). If you did send a custom request header via ajax, a user could monitor the network traffic with the browser & simply send that header again

Comment: Is it too much of a security risk if the user is able to view the JSON output? The data isn't anything sensitive, just a few addresses and html code for custom buttons.

Comment: Only you can say whether it's a risk, though it doesn't sound like it is. Remember that anything done via ajax is done by the 'user' (the browser) so is exposed. If you need to keep the data hidden you need to do the processing server-side, not client-side.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your inputs.